# How to turn on Gmail Android app text autocomplete

Tags: gmail

When I use Gmail's web version, it makes autocomplete suggestions to the text I'm typing (for example, if I type "long time no" `see` might show in autocomplete). It also underlines in red grammar mistakes and suggests grammar improvements underlining the text in blue.

I recently bought myself an android tablet (Samsung A7). I tried using Gmail Android app because it's hard for me to use the web version with my tablet. The app works fine, but it doesn't give me the above text autocomplete feature nor the grammar notifications.

Is there a way to enable this? [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqsuuVc_xAw) goes through pretty much all settings and, although it lists an autoreply feature, I can't find anything about text autocomplete or grammar. Is this possible at all on the Android app?

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Gmail, go to Settings.
2. Select your account. Enable Smart Reply in email

[image: IMG:]

Comment: Thank you! but even when I enable these options it still doesnt work, I neither get writing suggestions nor squiggly underlines for grammatical mistakes. I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Tab A7